# C++ - Alternative for auto and decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

every body.
I was reading a c++ code and I face with this 2 template.

first:

```
template <class T>
float wrap_360(const T angle, float unit_mod)
{
    const float ang_360 = 360.f * unit_mod;
    float res = fmodf(static_cast<float>(angle), ang_360);
    if (res < 0) {
        res += ang_360;
    }
    return res;
}
```

and the second one is :

```
template <class T>
auto wrap_360_cd(const T angle) -> decltype(wrap_360(angle, 100.f))
{
    return wrap_360(angle, 100.f);
}
```

the first one is obvious for me , but what exactly the second one wants to say ??

Actually, my compiler does not support c++ 11 and so does not recognize "auto" and "decltype".

how can I change this code to be understandable for under c++11 compiler?

any help would be great. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which c++ compiler are you using?

Comment: Get out of the dark ages. This is technology, informatics. Move on.

Comment: `wrap_360()` returns a `float` independent of the argument type `T`. If this is the only overload, you can just use `float wrap360_cd(const T angle)`.

Comment: I think the second one is just being overly general, to allow for future overloads of `wrap_360` that have different return types. If there are no overloads, you can just use `float wrap_360_cd(const T angle)`

Answer (score 4):

The use of decltype() looks to be redundant in this case. You should be able to just replace that second function with the following:

```
template <class T>
float wrap_360_cd(const T angle)
{
    return wrap_360(angle, 100.f);
}
```

For future reference the code following the -> is called a trailing return type, which is required if your function return type is specified using the auto keyword (this can be useful in some situations for example when you want to use decltype() to specify the return type, though in this case it is not needed as you know the return type of the wrap_360() function already).